# Einschub oder Anfügung?

Tags: comma

Ich habe eine Klausur nachkorrigiert und bin an einer Stelle hängen geblieben. Es geht nicht um den speziellen Satz (keine Off-Topic-Korrektur / Wörter Erklärung), sondern :
Können durch ein Komma abgetrennte Einschübe auch mit einer Präpositon beginnen?

Folgender Satz wurde angestrichen, ich bin der Meinung, dass er funktioniert : "Es wurde gesagt, dass Schuhe früher, bei Sportlern beispielsweise, echte Klötze waren."

Laut Erstkorrektur ist "bei Sportlern beispielsweise", kein Einschub. Ich bin der Meinung, dass es je nach Semantik aber gerechtfertigt ist, Kommata zu setzen.

Comment: Denke ich auch.

Comment: Hier zieht §78 der Rechtschreibregeln: "*Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Satz bleibt vollkommen bedeutungsgleich, wenn man die Reihenfolge innerhalb des Einschubs (ich behaupte, es ist einer) umdreht:

> Es wurde gesagt, dass Schuhe früher, beispielsweise bei Sportlern, echte Klötze waren.

Die Frage, ob der Einschub auch mit einer Präposition beginnen darf, erübrigt sich deswegen. Ich denke nicht, dass sich deswegen die Regeln der Zeichensetzung verändern...

Und dann *müssen* dann nach meinem Gefühl Kommata stehen. Die Rechtschreibregeln erwähnen (§77(4)) "zum Beispiel" als typische Einleitung einer nachgestellten Erläuterung, die durch Kommata abzutrennen wäre. Ich sehe keinen Grund, warum das nicht gelten sollte, wenn "beispielsweise" hinten steht.

Darüberhinaus das, was in meinem Kommentar oben steht - Meine Lieblingsrechtschreibregel (§78):

> *Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.*